# Ubuntu 18.04 Hover / Tooltips broken

Tags: 18.04, gnome

Since a few days my tooltips in Ubuntu are broken. Sometimes they work but most of the time, they look like this:

[Broken tooltip in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gClCT.png)

[Broken tooltip in PhpStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h98Y5.png)

I couldn't find anything on this issue online. I haven't done anything related to upgrading or video card drivers and it worked flawlessly before.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 (5.3.0-26-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP) on an old iMac with a Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT.

Comment: You haven't given any details (ie. what kernel/software stack you are using? 18.04.3? with HWE, non-HWE, what video driver you are using?  what screen hardware you have etc), but I suspect it's `radeon` and it maybe related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/fedora/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/1841718  but without any specifics, that's guess only.

Comment: Apologies, I updated my original post